# HomeKit + KNX / industry standard bridge

Tags: smart-home, apple-homekit, knx

I am relatively new to home automation and was wondering what would be the industry standard bridge to make KNX homes work with HomeKit.

I am primarily interested in understanding features, cost effectiveness, reliability and preferences from those who are accustomed to the topic.